# How can I deploy JMS project using IBM MQ into JBoss?

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly, ibm-mq

I created a mini JMS project that can communicate with IBM MQ that's running in a local Docker container. Can this project be deployed in JBoss / Wildfly?

```java
 consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer"));
        context.start();
        System.out.println("Start listening to queue...");
        Thread.sleep(300000);
        context.close();

        recordSuccess();
```

Comment: Typically in a Java EE container like JBoss or WildFly you'd use an MDB to consume messages rather than manually configuring MessageListeners in your application. MDBs provide a lot of benefits like pooling and automatic JTA transaction enlistment. You'd also deploy and configure the IBM MQ JCA resource adapter for the MDB to use. If you don't want any of this functionality then you can deploy your basic application as well.

Comment: In addition what @JustinBertram commented, please read specifically [Installing and testing the resource adapter in Wildfly](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q129260_.html) and also more generically [Using the IBM MQ resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031610_.html).

Comment: @DanielSteinmann, I created resource-adapter in the standalone-full.xml file and run the IVT application . All the stages have passed except the 'Receiving response message from the MDB... failed to receive response message!' Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @IlanMiller The IVT application does not work properly. I opened a case last summer and it was fixed in November under APAR IT33764. But it is not included in an official MQ release yet. My next comment summarises my workarounds to get the IVT working.

Comment: The Installation Verification Test (IVT) failed because the MDM did not start. I had to make following changes inside `WMQ_IVT_MDB.jar` of `wmq.jmsra.ivt.ear`: 1) The activation configuration `DestinationLookup` and `ConnectionFactoryLookup` in `ejb-jar.xml` start with capital letter; it must be `destinationLookup` and `connectionFactoryLookup`. 2) There are activation configuration properties inside 
`jboss-ejb3.xml` to configure the same queue manager settings as already defined in `standalone-full.xml`. I had to remove those to use my configuration in `standalone-full.xml`.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann, Do you have Java code example of how to consume messages from IBM MQ With JBoss (using resaource adapter)?

Comment: There is a JEE tutorial [Receiving Messages Asynchronously Using a Message-Driven Bean](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-examples006.htm#BNBPK). You can also peek into the IVT that IBM provides.